# Office 365 rule to permanently delete emails

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web

I have an Office 365 mail rule to delete certain emails.  Unfortunately Jira sends individual emails for every little thing and there are very few I care about, so I receive hundreds a day that I want deleted.

A rule to delete email moves it to the trash where it'll sit for some time before being permanently removed.  I like to keep other trash for 30 days. Is there a way to configure a rule in mail that permanently deletes instead of moves to trash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a way to configure a rule in mail that permanently deletes instead of moves to trash?**

No, unfortunately there is not. The only **rule** to delete that is available for Outlook Web App (OWA) is just to move items to the Deleted Items folder. However some alternatives are:

**Automatically move files to a folder and permanently delete manually**

1. Open OWA.
2. From the left menu, right-click the name of the inbox and select **Create new folder**.
3. Name the folder accordingly. For example: **To be deleted**.
4. From the header, click the **cog** icon and select **Options**.
5. Select **Mail** > **Automatic processing** > **Inbox and sweep rules**.
6. Click the **+** icon to create a new rule.
7. Fill out the corresponding fields:

   - **Name**: The name of the rule.
   - **When the message arrives**: The conditions so that only the needed emails are selected. In this case, you would select: **It was sent or received** > **Received from** > **email@address.com>**.
   - **Do all of the following**: The actions that will be taken. In this case, you would select **Move, copy, or delete** > **Move the message to folder** > **To be deleted**.
8. Clear the check box for **Stop processing more rules**.
9. Click **OK**.
10. Confirm that when an email from Jira arrives, it is automatically moved to the **To be deleted** folder.
11. Select all messages in the **To be deleted** folder, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to permanently delete all emails in that folder.
12. Create a repeating task to remind yourself to do this at frequent intervals.

**Automatically empty Deleted Items**

1. Open OWA.
2. From the head, click the **cog** icon and select **Options**.
3. Select **Mail** > **Automatic processing** > **Message options**.
4. Select the check box for the option **Empty the Deleted Items folder when I sign out**.
5. Click **Save**.